# Failable och non-failable initializers prevents me to extend NSView and implement NSCoding

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, swift, nscoding

I'm having problems implementing a **subclass** to `NSView` that implements `NSCoding`.

It seems like the declarations of `init(coder: NSCoder)` are conflicting in `NSView` and `NSCoding`.
`NSView` nowadays says it's failable, but `NSCoding` still says it's non-failable.

When I try to override `init(coder: NSCoder)` and do my custom initialisation, Xcode 6.1 gives me an error message:

> A non-failable initializer cannot chain to failable initializer
>   'init(coder:)' written with 'init?'

How am I supposed to do my custom init of my class?

Here's a silly example where I extend a view and I want to persist an additional click counter for my view.

```
import Cocoa
import Foundation

class MyView: NSView, NSCoding {

    var clickCounter:Int = 0

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        coder.encodeObject(self.clickCounter,
                forKey: "clickCounter")
    }

    override func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.encodeWithCoder(coder)
        coder.encodeObject(self.clickCounter, forKey: "clickCounter")
    }

    override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        clickCounter++
    }    
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't have to explicitly conform to  `NSCoding`, because `NSResponder` (superclass of `NSView`) already conforms to it.

```
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    self.clickCounter = coder.decodeObjectForKey("clickCounter") as Int
}
```

Comment: That satisfies the compiler, but it seems strange (to me): `NSCoding` requires `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`, i.e. a non-failable initializer, but `NSResponder`, `NSView` etc implement `init?(coder: NSCoder)`. – Perhaps a bug in the imported headers?

Comment: Yeah, I think so. :-/

Comment: Thanks! So to sum up the solution, I removed explicit conformance to NSCoding and added a ? to my init to make it failable. Still strange though, and I wonder how NSResponder manages to implement the required non-failable init from NSCoding within it's failable init. Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Man you saved me tons of frustration with this one. All the crap in the forums and docs but nothing really pointed this out. Thanks a bunch.